# Parsing Youtube Statistics Returned as JSON in R

Tags: json, r, youtube

I have a problem with a function to get youtube statistics, it fails when the video doesn’t have all the fields. Here is my code and the api response. Any help to modify my code? Thanks

```
youtube.key <- "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

getYoutube <- function(youtube.video) {
  youtube.url <- paste0("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=", 
                    youtube.video, "&key=", 
                    youtube.key, 
                     "&fields=items(id,snippet(channelId,title,categoryId),statistics)&part=snippet,s    tatistics", sep="")
  youtube.json <- getURL(youtube.url);
  youtube.json <- rjson::fromJSON(youtube.json);
  if(as.numeric(length(youtube.json$items) > 0)) {
  stats <- youtube.json$items[[1]]$statistics;
  snippet <- youtube.json$items[[1]]$snippet;
  df <- data.frame("youtube" = youtube.video, 
                 "youtube.category" = snippet[["categoryId"]],
                 "youtube.views" = as.integer(stats[["viewCount"]]),
                 "youtube.likes" = as.integer(stats[["likeCount"]]),
                 "youtube.dislikes" = as.integer(stats[["dislikeCount"]]),
                 "youtube.comments" = as.integer(stats[["commentCount"]]))
 }
 return(df);
}

youtube.video <- c("kAkoJN0aI70", "qWTPRvr50jo")

df <- do.call(rbind, lapply(youtube.video, 
                        function(youtube.video) 
                          getYoutube(youtube.video)))
```

The API response:

```
[{
 "items": [
  {
   "id": "kAkoJN0aI70",
   "snippet": {
   "channelId": "UCzmcJRoEGvKEGjJvhBkMn4g",
   "title": "Aviones de Madera por Sergio Morera M.",
   "categoryId": "24"
   },
   "statistics": {
   "viewCount": "583",
   "likeCount": "2",
   "dislikeCount": "0",
   "favoriteCount": "0",
   "commentCount": "0"
   }
  }
 ]
},

{
 "items": [
  {
   "id": "qWTPRvr50jo",
   "snippet": {
   "channelId": "UC1Pp8vqtfjNOjHFTCCSQfPg",
   "title": "juguetes juguetes aviones avion disney dusty hopcopper bombero    firefighter planes disney",
   "categoryId": "22"
   },
   "statistics": {
   "viewCount": "982",
   "favoriteCount": "0",
   "commentCount": "0"
   }
  }
 ]
}]
```

Comment: Do did neither provide a reproducible example nor a valid json file, but I guess you are looking for `do.call(dplyr::rbind.fill, ...)`

Comment: (JSON only required a minor tweak) what exactly _fails_? Others use a function like [this](https://github.com/hadley/xml2/blob/master/R/utils.R) to help with `NULL` returned values, but we can't run your code w/o an API key since you haven't abstracted the data extraction from the URL grabbing and we don't know which JSON package you are using.

Comment: I´m using "rjson", and the error is:
Error in data.frame(youtube = youtube.video, youtube.category = snippet[["categoryId"]],  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 0

Comment: those'd be the `NULL`s. Try using the function in the link in my comment like: `as.integer(stats[["dislikeCount"]] %||% 0)`

Comment: Fantastic!! Thanks very much.